# How to use inheritance in java List?

Tags: java, inheritance

I want to inherit a DAG class which contains an ArrayList of Nodes. To inherit the ArrayList I have used `ArrayList<? extends Node>` but still I can't compile my code. Here's the code:

```
public class DAG {
    ArrayList<? extends Node> nodes;
    Node root;

    public DAG(Node root) {
        nodes = new ArrayList<>();
        this.root = root;
        nodes.add(root);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't include a snapshot, just paste the code and format (4-space indent).

Comment: (1) Put the actual code, not a "snapshot". (2) `but still I can't compile my code` why?

Comment: If you are using a wildcard as the generic type for your `List`, then you can't add to it, because the compiler has no way of knowing if whatever you are adding matches the wildcard. So don't use a wildcard for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ArrayList` is of generic type which inherits from `Node`, and not `Node`, but you add a `Node` to it, which might be the wrong type - that causes the compilation error, since this operation might be unsafe. (See explanation at the end of the answer)

One way to handle it is to declare your `ArrayList` as `ArrayList<Node>`, instead of `ArrayList<? extends Node>`.

Another option is to declare the `DAG` class as a generic class:

```
public class DAG <T extends Node> { 
   ArrayList<T> nodes;
   T root;

   public DAG(T root) {
      /...
   }
}
```

---

Why is it unsafe?

Look at the following code:

```
public static class A { 

}
public static class B extends A { 

}
public static class C extends A { 

}
public static <T extends A> void foo(ArrayList<T> arr, A a) {
    arr.add(a); //this fails at compilation

}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<B> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    foo(arr, new C());
    B b = arr.get(0);

}
```

If the addition would have been successful - you would get a run time error!

Comment: I have used a generic ArrayList because ArrayList<B> and ArrayList<A> aren't equivalent and in a previous question which I asked it was suggested to use generic ArrayList, but it has problem yet. None of using ArrayList<Node> and ArrayList<? extends Node> is usefull

Comment: @amirveyseh THen you might want to make the class generic. See edit.

Comment: *"Your ArrayList is of generic type which inherits from Node, and not Node, but you add a Node to it,"* ... I have no way to understand what this even means.  It seems bizarre on so many levels.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what `ArrayList<? extends Node>` means. It basically an ArrayList with element of a type that extends `Node`. That element can be `Node` or other types which inherit `Node`.

Perhaps this is what you need:

```
class A { 

}

class B extends A { 

}

class C extends A { 

}


List<T extends A> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
B b = new B();
C c = new C();
nodes.add(b);
nodes.add(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example I would have done:

```
public class DAG { 
    ArrayList<Node> nodes;
    Node root;

    public DAG(Node root) {
        // ..
    }
}
```

That way `nodes` can contain objects of type `Node` and any types that inherit from `Node`.